# Unable to reference generated resource from code

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources, android-build, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a configuration template file which has placeholders to fill out based on the current build flavor (`devDebug`, `prodRelease`, etc.).

I've decided to create and inject a custom Gradle task into the build flow which properly runs and creates the correct configuration file into the main resources folder (`main/res/raw`).

My goal is to output the generated config file into the build folder's generated resources, e.g. `$buildDir/generated/res/myconfig/dev/debug/raw/config.json`. I can set the path for the output to be like it and the file gets created but I'm stuck when trying to access it from code. Also AS doesn't recognise the folder `myconfig` as resources root (even if explicitly marking it). What do I miss here?

Here's the Gradle task doing the work (it's Kotlin):

```
fun configureMyConfiguration(variant: ApplicationVariant) {
    getTasksByName(
        "generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Resources",
        true
    ).onEach { task ->
        task.dependsOn(
            task("${variant.name}ConfigureMyConfiguration") {
                group = "MyApp"
                description = "Configure my configuration"

                doLast {
                    val configRoot = File("$buildDir/generated/myconfig/${variant.flavorName}/${variant.buildType.name}/res")
                    val templateFile = "$rootDir/app/config_template.json"
                    val configFile = File(configRoot, "raw/my_config.json")
                    val config = File(templateFile).readText()
                        .replace("\${foo}", "bar")

                    configFile.ensureParentDirsCreated()
                    configFile.createNewFile()
                    configFile.writeText(config)

                    project.android.sourceSets.getByName(variant.name) {
                        resources.srcDir(configRoot)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

The method to setup tasks is called when configuring application variants:

```
applicationVariants.all {
    outputs.forEach {
        configureMyConfiguration(this@all)
    }
}
```

As you can see folders and file gets created successfully in build folder:

[image: generated resources]

However referencing from code doesn't work I suppose because the generated sources are not recognised and assembled properly.

[image]

I tried to add the generated folder to the source sets in the `android` block of the gradle file - this way the folder got marked as resource root but referencing from code still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While experimenting with Paul Ost's answer I came across a working solution.

Basically all you need to do is calling `variant.registerGeneratedResFolders(files(configRoot))` which is going to register the generated folder as resources root so that values there gonna be accessible through `R.`.

Important part is that this shouldn't be inside the task, but before the task injection and creation happen. I'm not sure why. Also, manually adding a source root is not needed, since it won't affect the outcome. See the corrected code for the task below.

```
fun configureMyConfiguration(variant: ApplicationVariant) {
    val configRoot = File("$buildDir/generated/myconfig/${variant.flavorName}/${variant.buildType.name}/res")

    // Registering folder as recognized resourced root
    variant.registerGeneratedResFolders(files(configRoot))

    getTasksByName(
        "generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Resources",
        true
    ).onEach { task ->
        task.dependsOn(
            task("${variant.name}ConfigureMyConfiguration") {
                group = "MyApp"
                description = "Configure my configuration"

                doLast {
                    val templateFile = "$rootDir/app/config_template.json"
                    val configFile = File(configRoot, "raw/my_config.json")
                    val config = File(templateFile).readText()
                        .replace("\${foo}", "bar")

                    configFile.ensureParentDirsCreated()
                    configFile.createNewFile()
                    configFile.writeText(config)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

So the `resValue` does not work with raw values so the working way is to register path of your file as `res` path for android

As @bearlysophisticated [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61122223/9248201) do it like this

```
    val configRoot = File("$buildDir/generated/myconfig/${variant.flavorName}/${variant.buildType.name}/res")

    // Registering folder as recognized resourced root
    variant.registerGeneratedResFolders(files(configRoot))
```

Do it out of the task loop. Better before.

**Edit end**

The problem is you create file but you never let Android framework to index it. That means that the file actually exists but it is not added to R.java file with resources references. Gradle has such possibility :

<del>you may do something like 
`resValue "raw", "json_name", file`</del> *Does not work - see **Edit** section above*

I am not sure this will work with raw resource since I haven't tried it in actual code - but with strings and ints it works perfectly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach is not good: `resValue` doesn't support raw files. Gives the following exception when trying to do what you proposed: `invalid value for type 'raw'. Expected a reference.` I'm not sure how to set reference as value. However I found another, finally working solution when implementing yours. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Cheers mate